# My app is terminated when i launch it to my device through android studio

Tags: android, xml

I created a simple app that the only thing that does is to print "Hello world".
When i try to launch it on my device in some point it stops and says "Unfortunately ,(the name of my app) has stopped. " I searched everywhere, but I couldn't find a solution to this problem.

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml(if this is helpful.) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.test">

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

logcat:

```
Process: com.example.android.test, PID: 6266
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.test/com.example.android.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at com.example.android.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I hope this is what is required to help me solve this problem. If you need some more declerations please let me know.

EDIT

here is my Main.Activity.java code:

```
package com.example.android.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Example of a call to a native method
    //TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
    //tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
}

/**
 * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
 * which is packaged with this application.
 */
public native String stringFromJNI();

public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Create the variable
    TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Other view stuff

        // Get the reference
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        // Now you can do things to the Textview like change its text
        mTextView.setText("Hello world!");

    }

}
```

}

Comment: please share you MainActivity.java code. may be you try to setText of a null TextView

Comment: The Error Message indicates that you didn't instantiate your TextView. As you didn't specify an `android:id` in your TextView's XML, my guess is that while you did declare the `TextView` in your `MainActivity`, you didn't instantiate it (using `findViewById(R.id.theTextViewId)` in your `onCreate`). But you have to share the relevant bits from your MainActivity to tell for sure

Comment: Although i solved the problem i added the Main.Activity.java code with some minor changes that i've made wich where provided by the guy that answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Logcat output it looks like you are trying to set the text of your TextView before getting your reference to it, try this.
First make sure you add the ID field to your xml.

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello_world"
android:textSize="36sp"
android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
android:layout_marginTop="12dp"

android:"@+id/text_view"
/>
```

Then open your MainActivity class and add the following to your class

```js
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  // Create the variable 
  TextView mTextView;

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Other view stuff

        // Get the reference 
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        // Now you can do things to the Textview like change its text
        mTextView.setText("Hello World!");
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a little advice for next time : if the first lines of logcat output don't​ make sense, keep on reading :) try to find your apps package name, then go from there :)